# Why do two concurrent queues created by DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT not running concurrently?

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, multitasking

To execute two tasks concurrently, I made two concurrent queues and dispatched some blocks to both the queues.

Here is what I am doing in main thread

```
-(IBAction)btn_Pressed:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue_a = dispatch_queue_create("com.gcd_demoA", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_queue_t queue_b = dispatch_queue_create("com.gcd_demoB", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

    dispatch_sync(queue_a, ^{
        NSLog(@"A - 1");
    });

     dispatch_sync(queue_a, ^{
        NSLog(@"A - 2");
    });

    dispatch_sync(queue_a, ^{
        NSLog(@"A - 3");
    });

    dispatch_sync(queue_b, ^{
        NSLog(@"B - 1");
    });

    dispatch_sync(queue_b, ^{
        NSLog(@"B - 2");
    });

    dispatch_sync(queue_b, ^{
        NSLog(@"B - 3");
    });
}
```

But, surprisingly I always get the following output:

```
A - 1  
A - 2  
A - 3  
B - 1  
B - 2  
B - 3
```

### Why these two concurrent queues don't execute concurrently ?

Here is what Apple document says ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_create)):

> Blocks submitted to a serial queue are executed one at a time in FIFO order. Note, however, that blocks submitted to independent queues may be executed concurrently with respect to each other. Blocks submitted to a concurrent queue are dequeued in FIFO order but may run concurrently if resources are available to do so.

So, as per this statement, in my case, the blocks of queue B should execute regardless of what's happening in queue A. Means, totally independent than queue A. But, why the blocks of queue B don't start their execution until all blocks of queue A finish.

Correct me if something has been misunderstood.

Comment: The blocks you are running complete too quickly. Try doing longer running tasks in each block.

Comment: @rmaddy: By considering your comment, I put _for loop_ from 0 to 1000 in both the queues and logged it. Still both queues do not execute concurrently. I got completely serial output.

Comment: Right, but even with the change to using `dispatch_async`, your original blocks probably would have shown serial output. Now with longer running blocks, with logs at the start and end, you should now see overlapping output when used with `dispatch_async`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks for your reply. Loop from 0 to 1000 will take noticeable time. So, they should be overlapped. I can't understand exactly what you meant. Can you provide example ?

Comment: I was simply saying that you really had two problems - 1) Using `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`. 2) Blocks that ran too quickly to be useful to test concurrency. Without changing #2, you probably still would have thought you had issues even after fixing #1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rmaddy

Comment: I also have tried with loop from 0 to 10000, but same result. This loop is not a trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dispatch_sync means "wait until this is done before continuing". So you run one block, wait, run another block, wait, and so on. You have to use dispatch_async to get concurrency.

(edit) also there's no reason to create a second concurrent queue here, one will have the same effect

Comment: Then, what is the difference between creating serial queue and concurrent queue ? I get same output in both the cases of creating serial and concurrent.

Comment: dispatch_sync on a concurrent queue does effectively nothing, so pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: dispatch_async, however, will definitely behave differently. If you dispatch_async to a serial queue, it will be concurrent with the caller, but the blocks will not run concurrently with each other. If you dispatch_async to a concurrent queue, the blocks will run concurrently.

Comment: Thanks a lot Catfish_Man for your continuous support. I am clear now. dispatch_sync call or dispatch_async call matters in both the cases. Last question to you: Can you give me some tips in which scenarios, we should create concurrent queues and when to not...

Comment: For example, If I need to make 10 to 15 NSURLRequest concurrently, what would be the best practise ? (1) Creating one **SERIAL** queue and making 15 **dispatch_async** calls (2) Creating one **CONCURRENT** queue and making 15 **dispatch_async** calls. One thing is now clear that I will have to use **dispatch_async** call in such a case but which queue should I use in this case ?

Comment: Best practice there would be to use nsurlsession instead, really. There's a great deal of complexity to doing concurrent io well that it handles for you.